# How to add a minimize hint to QDialog?

Tags: pyqt5, pyside, pyside2

I have a dialog that is non-modal and appears on-top of other widgets in the application. But it's hidden when another window from a different application covers it. This is exactly what I'm after.

However, I'm struggling to add a minimize button to its title bar.

Here's a basic example with my initial attempt:

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class TestDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TestDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(200, 100)
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() |
                            QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint)

dialog = TestDialog()
dialog.show()
```

(But it doesn't add the minimize hint)

Here's an example that adds the minimize hint:

```
class TestDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TestDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(200, 100)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint |
                            QtCore.Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint)
```

(But the widget is hidden when I click somewhere else in the application)

And here's an example where it stays on top:

```
class TestDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TestDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(200, 100)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint |
                            QtCore.Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint | 
                            QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
```

(But this stays on-top of all windows, even from other applications)

Is there a way to add the minimize button without introducing undesirable side effects?

Thanks

Comment: Not related to your question but that's a strange `super` you have there. You could use simply `super().__init__(parent=parent)` to call the QDialog's `__init__`.

Comment: Thanks @Guimoute . I should have mentioned that this dialog is intended to work in python2.7 and python3.7. In 2.7 I get `TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)`

Comment: Window behavior might change a lot depending on the system. What you're asking and what you'll get might change on different OS. That said, please clarify on/for what system you're doing this.

Comment: Thanks @musicamante . I'm building the dialog to work on Linux CentOS7. And it's intended to run from an application called Nuke (developed by TheFoundry)

Comment: Ok, so it has to be cross-platform. One question, though: from what you're describing, it seems like you're not really looking for an actual dialog (which is normally intended to be temporarily used - hence, "dialog"), but maybe a popup/dock widget. That said, as the [documentation explains](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum), "The `CustomizeWindowHint` flag is used to enable customization of the window controls. This flag must be set to allow the [...] `WindowMinimizeButtonHint` [...] flags to be changed.". But you never used that flag.

Comment: I just tried `self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Dialog | QtCore.Qt.CustomizeWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint)` but it was still not showing the minimize button. The close button appears as expected.

Comment: Maybe a QDialog is not the right approach? Is there something else that would give me a non-modal window that stays on top of other widgets in the application, but does not cover windows from other applications? (And also allows me to add a minimize button)

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely not the correct answer. But I thought I'd share my workaround in case it's useful for anyone else.

This example includes an event filter that I've installed on the application instance. The filter emits a signal on click events which my dialog is using to raise itself above the application, but not above windows from other applications.

```
class TestDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        # Add Minimize Button
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Window |
                            QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint |
                            QtCore.Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint)

        # Raise the dialog on click events
        self._click_filter = ClickFilter()
        self._click_filter.clicked.connect(self.raise_)
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
        app.installEventFilter(self._click_filter)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        # Event filter no longer needed
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
        app.removeEventFilter(self._click_filter)
        event.accept()


class ClickFilter(QtCore.QObject):    
    clicked = QtCore.Signal()
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            self.clicked.emit()
        return False

dialog = TestDialog()
dialog.show()
```